# HTML5-data is not storing in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family: tahoma;
    }
    h2
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #data
    {
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }
</style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">       
    var prefix = "HTML5LocalStorage-";
    $("#save").click(function () {
        var key = $("#key").attr('value');
        var value = $("#value").attr('value');
        localStorage.setItem(prefix + key, value);          
        RewriteFromStorage();
    });

    function RewriteFromStorage() {
        $("#data").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
        {
            var key = localStorage.key(i); 
            if (key.indexOf(prefix) == 0) {
                var value = localStorage.getItem(key);                  
                var shortkey = key.replace(prefix, "");
                $("#data").append(
            $("<div class='kvp'>").html(shortkey + "=" + value)
               .append($("<input type='button' value='Delete'>")
                       .attr('key', key)
                       .click(function () { 
                           localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr('key'));
                           RewriteFromStorage();
                       })
                      )
        );
            }
        }
    }

    RewriteFromStorage();
</script>
<h2>
    LocalStorage Demo</h2>
<div id="data">
</div>
<hr />
<span>Key</span><input type="text" id="key" /><span>Value</span><input type="text"
    id="value" />
<input type="button" id="save" value="Save" />
```

I have written above lines of code in localstorage.htm page(visual studio 2010),But output is nothing in button click.What mistake i have done.I am new to this technology.

Comment: I have refered this link http://jsfiddle.net/Benjol/HMEVd/

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but in IE `localStorage` doesn't work on local pages.

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, but this - `.attr('value')` - is completely wrong. The current `value` is a property, not an attribute, and there's a built-in jQuery function specifically to get/set it called `.val()` which you should be using.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Teemu I am browsing the page in chrome.do you have any idea,how to store data in local storage.

Comment: Not having Chrome at hands just now, but your fiddle seems to work with FF and IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
    var key = $("#key").attr('value');
    var value = $("#value").attr('value');
```

Add the following to see the problem:

```
alert(key + ' ' + value);
```

Use `val` insead to get the value of the inputs...

```
var key = $("#key").val();
```

You can [see this working in my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSPZQ/).

Comment: have you tried without js fiddle.Where you have wriiten script tag(within the head or body)..

Comment: The script executes on the `onload` event - so you can place it wherever you like as long as you also attach it to the `onload` event. I usually place by scripts just before the `</body>` tag.